# Create EvenEmitter dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, observer-pattern, eventemitter

I am trying to implement Observer kind of pattern using EventEmitter in Angular.

For example I have a publisher called **component1Publisher**

```
component1Publisher: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

publishing the events like below

```
this.component1Publisher.emit(data);
```

Subscribe in multiple components like below

```
component1Publisher.subscribe((data:any) => {
            //do something here;

          });
```

You can see the publisher is statically declared.In my project publisher and subsciber is completely dynamic. So I want to create this EventEmitter instance and subscriber based on my unique component name.Something like below

```
createEvent(uniqueName:string){
//new unique eventEmitter
}
```

**My problem**
       I have a reusable framework to create a dashboard that user can bring widgets provided by the framework itself. So I am trying to communicate between widgets to make it interactive. For example when you click widget should notify all the other widgets.To do that I am planning to tell the user to provide an dynamic service. In dynamic service have some method like onWidgetClick(), which will fire by framework by dynamically resolve the service. In that method user can create an event to publish. It will notify all the widgets with the new data and framework will update it with new data(all the reusable widgets have the subscriber) .

Could you please help me on this or suggest is there any alternative  to do this kind of implementation

Comment: Updated question with actual requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a map (i think that's the right term?) inside whatever component/directive 'this' refers to. Something like:

```
componentPublishers: { [index:string] : EventEmitter<any> } = {};
```

That code just says, I'm creating an object that will contain EventEmitters, all identified by strings (you can use strings or numbers as identifiers, but in nearly all cases people use strings).

Then you can add EventEmitters to it with any name you like, by using the bracket notation (which is used in JS to add new properties to objects).

```
createEvent(uniqueName:string){
  this.componentPublishers[uniqueName] = new EventEmitter<any>();

 // and maybe you'd want to return it?

  return this.componentPublishers[uniqueName];
}
```

After its created, you should be able to access it like normal without bracket notation. By using the map as I have shown above, typescript will know that any property of the componentPublishers object will be an event emitter.

```
this.componentPublishers.myNewEventEmitter.emit('some value');
```

Note: you'll get errors if you try to use bracket notation to add properties to the object, if you don't instantiate it first. I just instantiated it as an empty object.

```
 ... =  {};
```

So make sure to do that.

You could also just create an array of event emitters and push new ones into it, but that gets clumsy very quickly bc you have to keep track of the indices. By using a map you can access them by name like a regular object, and still have Typescript's static type checking.

Comment: It's looks good to me. Let me try this solution. I have updated my question with actual requirement. did you think the solution provided by @DeborahK will meet my need. I don't think without observable it's not possible

Comment: I think you're right observables would be the best solution. You could also try creating rxjs Subjects instead of EventEmitters. They may be easier to handle, and they give you more options. Another thing that might help... you can deal with subscriptions imperatively by importing 'Subscription' from 'rxjs/Subscription'. That can save you a bit of repetitive coding if you're constantly sending Observables and then the recipient is immediately subscribing to them in most cases. It also lets you unsubscribe if the widget/component/whatever is destroyed.

Comment: I agree on that I have seen somewhere using rxJS Subjects. Thanks for your solution. I will try the same.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to ultimately accomplish, this may not be needed. You can leverage Angular's change detection to provide the notifications you need.

For example, you can set up a service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

Any templates bound to that data are automatically notified of the changes (no events necessary).

I have a blog post about it here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

And a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

Comment: it's framework so user should have an option to create an event based on the component name. The framework already subscribe with the unique name. So whenever publish an event it's fire all the component subscribed. In my thought event emitter is best fit for this requirement.

Comment: I have updated my question with my actual requirement